# Using "using" statement to dispose

Tags: c#, .net

Does this make sense ?

Having a simple class

```
   class Test
   {
     public Test()
     {
        // Do whatever
     }
   }
```

and then instantiating it

```
using(new Test())
{
  // Nothing in here
}
```

The using statement is there just to make sure Test is disposed.
When will it be disposed if I just call

```
new Test()
```

Comment: Is this under the assumption that `Test` implements `IDisposable`?

Comment: No it doesn't. How to know if a class needs to implement it or not ? Do you always do it ?

Comment: I *suspect* that you are confusing "gargage collection" and "disposal", which are two related but very different concepts.

Comment: I think he's probably used to C++ or the like where you'd need to delete an object after new'ing it.

Have a read about garbage collection.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Test` isn't `IDisposable`, so that won't even compile. But if it *was* disposable, yes `using` will do it, and `new` by itself **won't**. It is an *unusual* usage, but I've seen similar. Rarely.

Based on your comment (main question), I *suspect* that you are confusing garbage collection and disposal. There is no way to forcibly make something get collected, short of `GC` (which you should **not** do). Unless you have a *really* good reason to want it collected, just let it be - chances are it is "generation 0" and will be collected cheaply anyway.

Also, the "do whatever" suggests *doing* something in a constructor but not caring about the created object; a static method would be preferable:

```
public class Test { /* could be static */
     public static void DoSomething() { ... }
}
...
Test.DoSomething();
```

Comment: I'd argue on the 'unusual usage', in fact, I use it quite often.

Comment: @Yossarian - can you please explain why, and how is it better than a normal method?

Comment: well : some (initial) action is binded with another (final) action, for example: `HtmlWriter.RenderBeginTag()`, `RenderEndTag()`. If you throw exception between these two (or otherwise forget to `RenderEndTag`), it results in malformed html/xml. So, I wrote extension method over RenderBeginTag, which returns IDisposable class simply calling RenderEndTag, and I now clearly see, (via indentation) where is tag opened/closed. Another examples is measuring of how long did some block take to run. But, YMMV.

Comment: @Yossarian - this technique is called RAII (Resource Acquisition Is Initialization). @Kobi - RAII is a cornerstone of reliable software; it is not heavily used currently in .NET (for a variety of reasons), but is entering mainstream (witness, e.g., the Rx library).

Comment: @Yossarian - note the "Nothing in here"; it is *that* that makes it unusual

Comment: @Marc - Sorry, I take back my 'I'd argue' comment, I missed the 'Nothing in here' part.

Answer (score 2):

By not assigning the instance to a variable, it will be eligible for GC as soon as it goes out of scope.

Or, is there something else you are trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: Nothing else. As Marc underlined I was running my actions in the class constructor which seems to be bad (or at least unusual) practice. I don't need the class further then that.

Answer (score 0):

Recommended reading:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/bb985010.aspx